# Implementing soft server restart

Tags: c++

Currently i am working on our IMAP server and i need to implement some way to "graceful" server restart. We using `boost::asio` (but its not necessary). I need to keep current operations working for clients which already run an operation (e.g. Fetch), but new server instance(new version we are deploying) should intercept 143 & 993 ports and start accept clients to avoid downtime. Currently i have 2 ideas:

1. Listen unix domain socket for commands. Extendable, but harder to implement since need to "control socket", its transition to new server and so on..
2. Signal (e.g. USR1). Server does some cleanup, release listen ports, and then `fork()` and `exec()` into new instance which will continue to accept, while old instance does clean shutdown for already connected clients.
3. ... Any other ideas?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Is there a problem with implementing either of those two ideas?

Comment: @SamMiller i just looking for a better desision to do this. Probably i missed some other way how to do this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common convention for UNIX daemons is to do a soft restart in response to a `SIGHUP`. Exactly what that entails varies from program to program. Typically it means closing and reopening log files or re-reading their configuration files. A common use is to assist with log file rotation.

Why `SIGHUP`? The normal purpose of `SIGHUP` is to signal users' processes when that user is logging out. Daemons by definition have detached themselves from the user's session and TTY precisely to avoid being killed when the starting user logs out. So `SIGHUP` was repurposed to mean "soft restart".

**Bottom line:** Do #2 but with `SIGHUP`.